# Where to find/what is full μ-expression for Ackermann function?

Tags: logic, computability, ackermann-function

Can you point me to full description of the Ackermann function in terms of standard μ-opertor and primitive recursion? I understand that to define it completely down to primitive terms (numerals, composition, recursion and minimisation) would be quite lengthy, but I'm wondering what would it look like.

In answer to similar question, [Explicit mu-recursive expression for Ackerman function](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/explicit-mu-recursive-expression-for-ackerman-function), a user provided a sketch of such answer, but some details are missing and I'm not there yet in terms of my understanding.